# MYSQL Trigger is not being created

Tags: mysql, triggers

I am having difficulty understanding where the issue is with creating the trigger in the code below: Please assist.

```
CREATE TABLE staff (staff_id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, 
firstname VARCHAR(20)
, lastname VARCHAR(20), email VARCHAR(50));
INSERT INTO staff (firstname, lastname, email)
VALUES ('James', 'Kirby', 'jkirby@test.com'),
    ('Betty', 'Featherstone', 'bfeatherstone@test.com');
CREATE TABLE users (user_id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, 
username
 VARCHAR(20), email VARCHAR(50), 
staff_id INT,  FOREIGN KEY (staff_id) REFERENCES staff (staff_id))

DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER after_staff_insert AFTER INSERT ON staff
 FOR EACH ROW
 BEGIN
INSERT INTO users (username, email)
VALUES(CONCAT(NEW.firstname,NEW.lastname,NEW.staff_id),NEW.email);
 END //

DELIMITER;
```

Comment: Your create table users statement is not terminated.

Comment: If you move the insert to the end of the code and add the terminator this code 'works' with the possible exception of staff_id which you are not setting in users.

Comment: I've terminated that line now but still does not work. Thanks for spotting that.

Comment: @P.Salmon I'm not sure I understand what you mean in the second comment. I thought the insert statement is in the right place in the body of the trigger?

Comment: sorry I meant the insert to staff

Comment: Ok, got you now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot reproduce your problem after the changes I mentioned the code block works as expected. What ide are you using (phpmyadmin,mysqlworkbench) etc

```
drop table if exists s,u;

CREATE TABLE s (staff_id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, 
firstname VARCHAR(20)
, lastname VARCHAR(20), email VARCHAR(50));

CREATE TABLE u (user_id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, 
username
 VARCHAR(20), email VARCHAR(50), 
staff_id INT,  FOREIGN KEY (staff_id) REFERENCES staff (staff_id));

drop trigger if exists after_staff_insert;
truncate table debug_table;
DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER after_staff_insert AFTER INSERT ON s
 FOR EACH ROW
 BEGIN
INSERT INTO u (username, email,staff_id)
VALUES(CONCAT(NEW.firstname,NEW.lastname,NEW.staff_id),NEW.email,new.staff_id);

 END //
 delimiter ;

INSERT INTO s (firstname, lastname, email)
VALUES ('James', 'Kirby', 'jkirby@test.com'),
    ('Betty', 'Featherstone', 'bfeatherstone@test.com');


 select * from s;
 select * from u;

MariaDB [sandbox]>  select * from s;
+----------+-----------+--------------+------------------------+
| staff_id | firstname | lastname     | email                  |
+----------+-----------+--------------+------------------------+
|        1 | James     | Kirby        | jkirby@test.com        |
|        2 | Betty     | Featherstone | bfeatherstone@test.com |
+----------+-----------+--------------+------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.02 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]>  select * from u;
+---------+--------------------+------------------------+----------+
| user_id | username           | email                  | staff_id |
+---------+--------------------+------------------------+----------+
|       1 | JamesKirby1        | jkirby@test.com        |        1 |
|       2 | BettyFeatherstone2 | bfeatherstone@test.com |        2 |
+---------+--------------------+------------------------+----------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```